# Syncing two locally stored databases through

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, hsqldb

I have been given a project which involves syncing two databases. One of them is in HSQLDB and other one is in MySQL both stored on my Laptop. I want to use symetric ds  to sync these two databases but couldnt figure it out. If someone could provide a step by step guide for the same..

PS. I am really new to Symetric DS and Networks

Comment: Have you read the "Quick Start Tutorial" (https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.10/html/tutorials.html) and the "User Guide" (https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.10/html/user-guide.html)?

Comment: I'm afraid we can't provide you with a "step by step guide".  (We are not a tutorial or documentation writing service.  Or a documentation *finding* service.)  However, if you have a specific question, someone should be able to answer it.  For instance, you could show us what you have done so far and explain where you are stuck.